# How to invoke ActiveX procedure outside of it's Worksheet scope?

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, module, scope

I've got an extensive project.
Amongst other things, it contains an

- UserForm
- Worksheet (`Data`) with a button called `import_button`

Either way, I've got one procedure inside the `UserForm` vba code, which acts something akin to mine.

After it is executed, I wanted to `Call` the `import_button_Click` procedure, from the `Data` Worksheet, however obviously, the reference is unknown, given the `import_button_Click` procedure is `Private` inside the `Data` Worksheet module.

**Is there perhaps a way, I could invoke the `import_button_Click` procedure outside of the `Sheet1 (Data)` module?**

[image]

---

EDIT:

Should probably note, this is the structure of the `import_button_Click` procedure.

```
Public Sub import_button_Click()

    Dim prva As Range: Set prva = Sheets("Zdrojove").Range("A1")
    Call import_data(get_delimeter(prva, ";", ",", ".", "-", "/"), False) 
    Call validate_format

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to make it `Public Sub import_button_Click` then call it with `Sheet1.import_button_Click` (replace `Sheet1` with whatever the sheet's name is in the properties window).

Comment: @dwirony Perhaps I should expanded on my question, I already tried this. Returns with "Object doesn't support this method". Perhaps, it's because there are other Private procedures, which are invoked inside the `import_button_Click` procedure?

Comment: Object doesn't support this method, or object required? Can you show how you've setup `import_button_Click`?

Comment: Yeah hold on, will edit

Comment: The other procedures in the button shouldn't matter - you just need to have the `_Click` one be `Public Sub` - then as long as you fully qualify it with the `Sheet` (since there could be other command buttons with the same name on other worksheets) then it should work.

Comment: @dwirony actually weirdly enough, it were the `Private` procedures inside `Public import_button_Click` which needed to be changed to `Public` as well. Now it works :)

Comment: Strange, I tested with a command button containing both `Public` and `Private` procedures and it worked fine. Maybe those other 2 subs in there were the issue? Who knows :)

Comment: @dwirony Yeah hard to tell. Sadly I couldn't even manually debug (step), given the code was inside userform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recreate the issue once changing the `Sub` to `Public`. Inside `CommandButton1`:

[image: Cmd1]

Inside `Module1`:

[image: mod]

Running `Test`:

[image: clik]

Comment: Check my latest comment in the comment-chain @ question. Issue was caused by the nested procedures inside the `import_button_Click` which were `Private`, albeit `import_button_Click` was set to `Public`

Comment: @Rawrplus Ah that makes sense!

Comment: Either way, Decided to accept your answer, given your comments helped me to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

There're several ways to make it work:

> - You declare `import_button_Click` **Public**

```
Public Sub import_button_Click()
    'Your code
End Sub
```

---

> - You create another **Public** `Sub` (inside `Sheet1 (Data)`) to call the **Private** one.

```
Private Sub import_button_Click()
    'Your code
End Sub

'Use this outside the sheet
Public Sub public_import_button_Click()
    Call import_button_Click
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What private sub? Both of your subs here are public.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to replace the ActiveX button on the Worksheet by a [Form Control button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-15ba7e28-8d7f-42ab-9470-ffb9ab94e7c2). This would allow you to get the exact procedure, now hosted in a Module instead of in the Worksheet... Then you can get the button to execute whatever macro (or sub) you want, while being able to call this procedure from other piece of code at the same time.